# Prove that $x = x^{3}+0.001$ has a root near 0

Tags: functional-analysis, contraction-operator

How can i prove that $x = x^{3}+0.001$ has a root near $0$? And how does this root look like? I think that i need to use contraction mapping here, but i don't know how exactly. Any hints?

Comment: What does "near zero" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

It looks like posted solutions, while correct,  did not address the role of *theory of contraction mappings*.

There are iterative processes for finding real roots of an algebraic equations which can be justified by the the theory of contraction mappings. One such method is Newton-Raphson. 
Also check this:
[Polynomial Roots using Contractual Mapping](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/325059/polynomial-root-using-contraction-mapping-principle)

Source:
[Applications of Contraction Mapping](http://qwerty-2009.angelfire.com/contraction-mapping.html)

Comment: Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(x)=x^3+c-x$ where $0<|c|<1/\sqrt 8$ (e.g., $c=0.001$).
Then $f(c)=c^3$ and $f(2c)=8c^3-c=c(8c^2-1)$, so $f(c)f(2c)=c^4(8c^2-1)<0$. From the Intermediate Value Theorem, $f$ has a root between $c$ and $2c$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks, I needed to tighten the bounds on $c$ accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=x^3-x+0.001$.

Observing that close to $0$, $x^3$ is negligible, we try

$$f(0.001)=0.000000001>0$$ and which is very close to a root.

From this, the first Newton's iterate gives

$$0.001-\frac{f(0.001)}{f'(0.001)}=0.001000001$$

with $$f(0.001000001)=3\cdot10^{-15}>0,$$ even closer.

For safety we double the step,

$$0.001-2\frac{f(0.001)}{f'(0.001)}=0.001000002$$

and

$$f(0.001000002)=-0.000000001<0.$$

This gives us full guarantee of a root.

---

The next Newton's iterate is

$$0.001000001000003\cdots,$$ with $f=1.2\cdot10^{-20}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=x^3-x+.001.$  Then $f(0)=.001>0$ and $f(.1)=.002-.1<0$ so $f$ has a root between $0$ and $.1$.

Answer (score 1):

There is, BTW, a nice series expansion for the root of equation $x - x^3 = \epsilon$ near $x=0$:

$$ x = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(3k)!}{k! (2k+1)!} \epsilon^{2k+1} $$

which can be derived using the [Lagrange inversion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem).

Answer (score 0):

Note that we can factor as follows:
$$x^3-x = x(x+1)(x-1) = -0.001.$$
Let $x = 1/\epsilon,$ where $|\epsilon| << 1$.
$$\implies x^3-x \approx \frac{1}{\epsilon^3},$$
which is not consistent.  However, if $x = \epsilon$, then
$$x^3-x \approx -\epsilon,$$
which is consistent with the small constant $-0.001$ on the right hand side.

So, the equation must have a root near zero.

Comment: and how this root looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Or take $20$ seconds and plot the functions:

[image]

Comment: The question is "prove." A graph is helpful to see it is true, but it doesn't help for proving it.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: it is no big deal to evaluate at $0.001$ then at a close value in the right direction, to prove a change of sign.